# finding signs of 3 numbers

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

This is slightly more of a coding problem than a math problem but I think it is still relevant.

So let's say I have 3 numbers A,B,C and I can only call a given function if two are negative and one is positive or vice versa with 2 positive and one negative. Also I need to be able to tell which of the 3 numbers is the odd one out.

It's tedious and a little unclean looking to do:

if(A < 0 && B < 0 && C > 0)

{

```
  //C is odd one out;
```

} else if(A < 0 && B > 0 && C < 0){

```
 //B is odd one out
```

} etc...

Comment: You *really* shoould write mathematics using LaTeX: it's nearly impossible to understand what you wrote. In the FAQ section you'll find directions.

Comment: Is the objective to minimize typing time, programmer time, or computer time?  I suspect the if statements above minimize computer time.  I suspect BaronVT's approach minimizes typing time.  Both are easy to understand and verify, which probably meets the programmer time objective.

Comment: As I note below (in a comment to my solution), you could also compute oddoneout = (A*B*C > 0)*(min(A,B,C) < 0)*max(A,B,C) + (A*B*C < 0)*(max(A,B,C) > 0)*min(A,B,C) which would take more computational time (each logical statement and min/max has to be computed), and is probably harder to understand, but takes the least amount of code.

Comment: Also, regarding computer time, note that in OP's solution, worst case is 18 comparisons (6 cases x 3 comparisons to either find out A,B,C all +/-, or that they fall into the last case listed.) In the solution I give below, I think every case is 2 multiplications (A*B*C) and 5 comparisons (P > 0, and 2 comparisons each for a min and a max).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming none of them are zero,

```
let P = A*B*C
if P > 0                       % either + + + or + - - 
    if min(A,B,C) > 0
        print('invalid input') % corresponds to + + +
    else
        oddoneout = max(A,B,C)
    end
else                           % either - - - or + + -
    if max(A,B,C) < 0
        print('invalid input') % corresponds to - - -
    else
        oddoneout = min(A,B,C)
    end
end
```

Comment: I guess succinctly, you could write


    oddoneout = (A*B*C > 0)*(min(A,B,C) < 0)*max(A,B,C) + (A*B*C < 0)*(max(A,B,C) > 0)*min(A,B,C)


which will return 0 if the input is invalid, or the 'odd one out' if it is valid. (here, the logical statements like (A*B*C > 0) will return 1 if true, and 0 if false.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply, if the product $ABC$ is positive then return a positive variable and if $ABC$ is negative then return a negative variable.

**Edit** added sample code.

```
if ABC > 0:
    for X in [A, B, C]:
        if X > 0: return X
else:
    for X in [A, B, C]:
        if X < 0: return X
```

Comment: I need to know specifically which one of A B and C is the odd one out and return that value, it can't just be any random positive or negative variable.

Comment: @user1855952: I added a sample code. I suppose this makes sense to you. This is what you want, right?